# How to convert different cell value to single row using vba in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to transfer data from one sheet to another.

1. My sheet1 is "form" type sheet. I have command button in it.
2. On pressing of command button cell value should be copied to another Sheet2.
3. I want every copy of value should be in one row and fixed column.
4. It should not be overwrite but enter in next empty row.

[image]

I am using below VBA code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1,A2,B1,B2,B3")

    For Each cell In rng
        'here you copy to another sheet, one row lower
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(cell.Row + 1, cell.Column).Value = cell.Value
    Next cell

    For x = lRow To 2 Step -1
        If Range("I" & x) <> vbNullString Then Range("I" & x).EntireRow.Delete
    Next x

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. It would help if you posted pictures of what you're starting with and what you want to end up with.

Comment: You forgot contact no. in the second image you post, you dont mention if Sheet1 has only one order, if has more than one order how is structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String, chara As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Set worksheet ws1
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2") '<- Set worksheet ws2
    End With

    Set rng = ws1.Range("B1:D1,B2:B6,B8:E11") '<- Set the range you want to loop

        For Each cell In rng

            If str = "" Then '<- Create a string with all details
            Else
                str = str & "," & cell.Value
            End If

        Next cell

        LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        i = 1

        For Each chara In Split(str, ",") '<- Split with commas

            ws2.Cells(LastRow + 1, i) = chara

            i = i + 1

        Next chara

End Sub
```